# Merging dataframes in R

Tags: r, merge

I have two dataframes which I would like to merge based on a common column

```
 [dataset A][http://public.justcloud.com/dldzm0fnsp.4540049] 

 [dataset B][http://public.justcloud.com/dldzmx1758.4540049]
```

Using

```
    merged terms <- dd_B[dd_B$GOBPID %in% dd_A$GOBPID,]
```

gives me the following error

```
    <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I already tried using merge as well which gives me the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to *guess* that you used `read.csv` on these files. However, if you opened the files in a decent text editor, you would see that these are actually tab-delimited files, so the more appropriate tool would be `read.delim`.

Here's what I did:

```
df1 <- read.delim("~/Downloads/dd_a.csv", strip.white = TRUE)
df2 <- read.delim("~/Downloads/dd_B.csv", strip.white = TRUE)
out <- merge(df2, df1)

head(out)
#       GOBPID Pvalue OddsRatio ExpCount Count Size                                         Term
# 1 GO:0000038  0.036     7.008        0     2   49 very long-chain fatty acid metabolic process
# 2 GO:0006412  0.013     2.704        3     8  510                                  translation
# 3 GO:0006413  0.001    11.556        0     4   62                     translational initiation
# 4 GO:0006414  0.022     9.417        0     2   37                     translational elongation
# 5 GO:0006448  0.036    32.723        0     1    6       regulation of translational elongation
# 6 GO:0006457  0.041     2.753        2     5  308                              protein folding
```

Comment: Previously, I read the file using " read. delim" but STRIP.WHITE=TRUE worked ! Thanks.